# Подзапрос одиночной строки возвращает более одной строки

Tags: sql, oracle

Здравствуйте. Есть проблема с выборкой запроса. Вот мой запрос:

```
select *
  from (select r.id,
               (select OPERATOR_ID
                  from TESC4.JOURNAL_RECORDS ref
                 where ref.ORIGINAL_REC_ID = r.ID) as oper,
               (select STRING_VALUE
                  from TESC4.JOURNAL_FIELD_DATA f
                 where r.id = f.journal_record_id
                   and field_name = 'INSTRUMENT_NUMBER') INSTRUMENT_NUMBER
          from TESC4.JOURNAL_RECORDS r
         where r.edit_state in (0, 1, 2)
           and r.journal_id = :JOURNAL_ID
           and r.journal_table_id = :JOURNAL_TABLE_ID
           and r.primary_date >= :START_DATE
           and r.primary_date < :END_DATE)
where INSTRUMENT_NUMBER like '%121339%';
```

В поле оператор подзапрос выдаёт более одной записи. В следствии чего и сыпеться ошибка. Как развернуть запрос так что бы посмотреть что выдаёт мой подзапрос?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот изначальный запрос.

```
select * from (select rownum rn, tb.* from (select * from
                 (
                    select r.ID REC_ID, r.ORIGINAL_REC_ID, r.PARENT_REC_ID, r.FIRST_REC_ID, r.PRIMARY_DATE, r.REC_DATE, r.FIRST_REC_DATE, r.OPERATOR_ID, r.OPERATOR_DOMAIN, r.EDIT_STATE,
                    NVL((select OPERATOR_ID from TESC4.JOURNAL_RECORDS where ID=r.FIRST_REC_ID), OPERATOR_ID) FIRST_OPERATOR_ID, (case when r.EDIT_STATE<>0 then (select OPERATOR_ID from TESC4.JOURNAL_RECORDS ref where ref.ORIGINAL_REC_ID=r.ID) else NULL end) DELETED_OR_UPDATED_BY, (case when r.EDIT_STATE<>0 then (select OPERATOR_DOMAIN from TESC4.JOURNAL_RECORDS ref where ref.ORIGINAL_REC_ID=r.ID) else NULL end) DELETED_OR_UPDATED_BY_DOMAIN, (case when r.EDIT_STATE<>0 then (select REC_DATE from TESC4.JOURNAL_RECORDS ref where ref.ORIGINAL_REC_ID=r.ID) else NULL end) DELETE_OR_UPDATE_DATE, (select STRING_VALUE from TESC4.JOURNAL_FIELD_DATA f where r.id=f.journal_record_id and field_name='INSTRUMENT_TYPE') INSTRUMENT_TYPE, (select STRING_VALUE from TESC4.JOURNAL_FIELD_DATA f where r.id=f.journal_record_id and field_name='INSTRUMENT_NAME') INSTRUMENT_NAME, (select STRING_VALUE from TESC4.JOURNAL_FIELD_DATA f where r.id=f.journal_record_id and field_name='TYPE_SIZE') TYPE_SIZE, (select STRING_VALUE from TESC4.JOURNAL_FIELD_DATA f where r.id=f.journal_record_id and field_name='INSTRUMENT_NUMBER') INSTRUMENT_NUMBER, (select STRING_VALUE from TESC4.JOURNAL_FIELD_DATA f where r.id=f.journal_record_id and field_name='INSTRUMENT_SERT') INSTRUMENT_SERT, (select STRING_VALUE from TESC4.JOURNAL_FIELD_DATA f where r.id=f.journal_record_id and field_name='INSTRUMENT_WORK') INSTRUMENT_WORK, (select DATE_VALUE from TESC4.JOURNAL_FIELD_DATA f where r.id=f.journal_record_id and field_name='INSPECTION_DATE') INSPECTION_DATE, (select STRING_VALUE from TESC4.JOURNAL_FIELD_DATA f where r.id=f.journal_record_id and field_name='AREA') AREA, (select STRING_VALUE from TESC4.JOURNAL_FIELD_DATA f where r.id=f.journal_record_id and field_name='SHOP_LINE') SHOP_LINE, (select STRING_VALUE from TESC4.JOURNAL_FIELD_DATA f where r.id=f.journal_record_id and field_name='NAZN') NAZN, (select NUMBER_VALUE from TESC4.JOURNAL_FIELD_DATA f where r.id=f.journal_record_id and field_name='IN_SHOP') IN_SHOP, (select STRING_VALUE from TESC4.JOURNAL_FIELD_DATA f where r.id=f.journal_record_id and field_name='SMENA') SMENA, (select STRING_VALUE from TESC4.JOURNAL_FIELD_DATA f where r.id=f.journal_record_id and field_name='OFFICER_PERSON') OFFICER_PERSON, (select STRING_VALUE from TESC4.JOURNAL_FIELD_DATA f where r.id=f.journal_record_id and field_name='STATUS') STATUS from TESC4.JOURNAL_RECORDS r 
                where r.edit_state in (0,1,2) and r.journal_id=:JOURNAL_ID and r.journal_table_id=:JOURNAL_TABLE_ID 
                and r.primary_date>=:START_DATE and r.primary_date<:END_DATE)  where (INSTRUMENT_NUMBER like '%121339%' and INSTRUMENT_NUMBER is not null ) order by PRIMARY_DATE, REC_ID)tb) where rn between 1 and 100;
```

Comment: «оператор» имеется ввиду `oper`? И что имеется ввиду под развернуть? Выполнить подзапрос отдельно?

Comment: @defaultlocale да и да. Хочу поглядеть что при таких же наложенных условиях приходит в подзапрос.

Answer (score 2):

Запрос, который покажет дубли:

```
select r.id, count(1) 
from   TESC4.JOURNAL_RECORDS r 
inner  join TESC4.JOURNAL_RECORDS ref
on     ref.ORIGINAL_REC_ID = r.ID
where  r.edit_state in (0, 1, 2)
and    r.journal_id = :JOURNAL_ID
and    r.journal_table_id = :JOURNAL_TABLE_ID
and    r.primary_date >= :START_DATE
and    r.primary_date < :END_DATE
group by r.id
having count(1) > 1
```

Запрос, аналогичный вашем, но без подзапросов, не будет валиться с ошибкой, если будут дубли(должны они быть или нет, скорее вопрос постановки задачи):

```
select * 
from 
(
  select r.id, 
         ref.OPERATOR_ID as oper, 
         f.STRING_VALUE as INSTRUMENT_NUMBER 
    from TESC4.JOURNAL_RECORDS r
    left join TESC4.JOURNAL_RECORDS ref
      on ref.ORIGINAL_REC_ID=r.ID
    left join TESC4.JOURNAL_FIELD_DATA f 
      on r.id=f.journal_record_id 
     and field_name='INSTRUMENT_NUMBER'
   where r.edit_state in (0,1,2) 
     and r.journal_id=:JOURNAL_ID 
     and r.journal_table_id=:JOURNAL_TABLE_ID 
     and r.primary_date>=:START_DATE 
     and r.primary_date<:END_DATE
)
where INSTRUMENT_NUMBER like '%121339%';
```

На этот запрос можно будет наложить группировку, чтобы посмотреть, что именно повторяется.

Comment: IDrakonl, не могли бы подсказать, я что то не пойму как положить сюда группировку что бы увидеть что именно повторяется.

Comment: Просто мне так же выдаёт выборку из 34 строк, которые выдавало по моему изначальному запросу. Если оттуда просто убрать подзапрос и этой колонки с оператором просто не было бы.

Comment: Поэтому и не могу понять в чём разница.

Comment: Не видя ключей ваших таблиц сложно угадать, как правильнее построить группировку. Просто отсортируйте ваши 34 строчки и найдите места, где будет 2 одинаковых строки

Comment: Глазами уже пробежал, двух одинаковых нет.

Comment: Получается, что в моём запросе вылетает ошибка что подзапрос одиночной строки, а в запросе который вы скинули нет повторяющихся записей. Точно он выдаёт результаты подзапроса?

Comment: Покажите ошибку, которая у вас получается

Comment: Моя ошибка. Результаты запроса были идиентичны оригинальному, но не отражали вашей проблемы. Исправил запрос, посмотрите теперь

Comment: Вставил в вопрос скрин ошибки если ещё нужен.

Comment: То же самое, нет повторяющихся строк. Но я скинул облегчённую версию своего запроса. На самом деле он гораздо больше. Возможно если я скину весь запрос будет понятнее? Ошибка та же самая само собой.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос изначальную версию запроса.

Comment: IDrakonl можете что то сказать? Почему не попадается задвоенных строк? Точно ваш запрос правильно составлен?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66535/discussion-between-ldrakonl-and-).

Answer (score 1):

Выполните подзапрос для выбора oper отдельно (если проблема в нем). Это поможет найти записи, в которых более одного `OPERATOR_ID`. Далее уже сможете посмотреть, почему их более одного.

```
select ORIGINAL_REC_ID, 
       OPERATOR_ID, 
       COUNT (OPERATOR_ID)
from   TESC4.JOURNAL_RECORDS ref
join   r.edit_state 
on     ref.ORIGINAL_REC_ID = r.ID
where  r.edit_state in (0, 1, 2)
and    r.journal_id = :JOURNAL_ID
and    r.journal_table_id = :JOURNAL_TABLE_ID
and    r.primary_date >= :START_DATE
and    r.primary_date < :END_DATE 
group  by ORIGINAL_REC_ID, OPERATOR_ID
having COUNT (OPERATOR_ID)>1
```